# Need to store bytes in common pattern irrespective of charset specified in request

Tags: java, character-encoding

I have a Java servlet which intercepts `POST` requests and stores the body (which is XML including special characters such as `á é í ó ú ñ ¡ ¿`, all representable in both `utf-8` and `iso-8859-1`) on the filesystem. The precise details of the storage container are not relevant; behavior is the same for a file or a database.

The `file.encoding`/default charset of the system is `iso-8859-1`, and cannot be changed.

Here's the problem: how do I arrange to store the bytes of the request (a Java object is serialized), whichever charset is specified in the `POST` `Content-Type`, in a form which, when subsequently retrieved by a further request, are independent of the `Accept-Charset` then specified?

What I have tried so far: transcoding the bytes to the default charset before saving:

```
// now that the request data has been cleaned and validated, 
// reconstruct the request bytes in the original charset
byte [] requestBytes = toBytes(String.valueOf(requestData),
requestCharset);

// transcode bytes to the default charset for ultimate storage in the database
byte [] bytes = transcode(requestBytes, requestCharset, Charset.defaultCharset());

// reconstruct the character array of the request in the default charset
char [] data = fromBytes(bytes, Charset.defaultCharset()).toCharArray();
...

...do more stuff and save data as bytes

static byte[] transcode(byte[] bytes, Charset from, Charset to) {
    return fromBytes(bytes, from).getBytes(to);
}

static String fromBytes(byte [] bytes, Charset charset) {
    return new String(bytes, charset);
}

static byte [] toBytes(String str, Charset charset) {
    return str.getBytes(charset);
}
```

Unfortunately this results in different storage patterns for the two charsets and hence different retrieval results: e.g.

`specialCharst�S1aÃºÃ©Ã³Â®Ã±Ã¡Å¸x` vs `specialCharst�S1aÃƒÂºÃƒÂ©ÃƒÂ³Ã‚Â®ÃƒÂ±ÃƒÂ¡Ã…Å¾x`

and clearly these would have to be identical for the requirements to be satisfied.

It is not possible to store the charset along with the body - this is a legacy system.

Comment: Store as [Unicode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/text/unicode.html)?

Comment: Edited question; yes.

Comment: Regardless of the native file encoding of the system, why not just store the text as UTF-8?  If writing to a file, designate the file a binary file;  if writing to a database, use a binary column.  Or are you not able to change the database schema?

Comment: Changing this is not permissible. This is an enterprise system and such a change would requiring several levels of approval which would not be forthcoming.

Comment: Kayaman had posted something which I was going to try, but now the answer is deleted and the question is downvoted. Seriously? LOL.

Comment: I am going to try it. What do you mean "when you had the chance"? Man, what is your problem?

Comment: After re-reading your question a few times, I get the impression that all of the incoming data is already ISO 8859-1, so what is the problem?  You can always encode your response in the charset specified in Accept-Charset.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to resolve this issue. The server-side code above is actually correct. However, the client was behaving in such a way as to mask this, by sending different data.

This was not apparent to the development team here (including me); *tut mir leid.*